# Python IF statement with nltk.wordnet.synsets

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

output=[]
wordlist=[]

entries = nltk.corpus.cmudict.entries()

for entry in entries[:200]: #create a list of words, without the pronounciation since.pos_tag only works with a list
    wordlist.append(entry[0])

for word in nltk.pos_tag(wordlist): #create a list of nouns
    if(word[1]=='NN'):
        output.append(word[0])

for word in output:
    x = wn.synsets(word) #remove all words which does not have synsets (this is the problem)
    if len(x)<1:
        output.remove(word)

for word in output[:200]:
    print (word," ",len(wn.synsets(word)))
```

I am trying to remove all the words without synsets but for some reason it isn't working. Upon running the program i find that even though a word is said to have len(wn.synsets(word)) = 0, it is not removed from my list. Can somebody tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't iterate over a list, and remove the current item at the same time. Here is a toy example which demonstrates the problem:

```
In [73]: output = range(10)

In [74]: for item in output:
   ....:     output.remove(item)
```

You might expect all the items in `output` to be removed. But instead half of them still remain:

```
In [75]: output
Out[75]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

---

**Why you can't loop and remove at the same time:**

Imagine Python using an internal counter to remember the index of the current item as it goes through the `for-loop`.

When the counter equals 0 (the first time through the loop), Python executes

```
output.remove(item)
```

Fine. There is now one less item in `output`. But then Python increments the counter to 1. So the next value of word is `output[1]`,
which is the *third* item in the original list.

```
0  <-- first item removed
1  <-- the new output[0] ** THIS ONE GETS SKIPPED **
2  <-- the new output[1] -- gets removed on the next iteration
```

---

**The (workaround) solution:**

Instead, either iterate over a copy of `output`, or build a new list. In this case, I think it is more efficient to build a new list:

```
new_output = []
for word in output:
    x = wn.synsets(word) 
    if len(x)>=1:
        new_output.append(word)
```